# CatBoost: negative values of probability

Tags: python, catboost

I try to predict values with `CatBoostRegressor`

But I get some negative values in predictions.

How can I fix that?

All code

```
X_train, y_train = train[['Distance', 'DepTime']].values, train['dep_delayed_15min'].map({'Y': 1, 'N': 0}).values
X_test = test[['Distance', 'DepTime']].values

X_train_part, X_valid, y_train_part, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.3, random_state=17)

model_cbr = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=500, loss_function='RMSE', learning_rate=1, depth=7).fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = model_cbc.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the data. It's impossible to reproduce your results from your current code snippet.

Comment: @Perfi train - https://github.com/Yorko/mlcourse_open/blob/master/data/flight_delays_train.csv test - https://github.com/Yorko/mlcourse_open/blob/master/data/flight_delays_test.csv

Comment: @Perfi i've added code to question

Comment: I think you need to update the catboost.